# How to upload the magento extension manualy without magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have a magento extension .zip file. I need to install the extension manually without magento connect.

Answer (score 2):

Unzip the archive over your magento instance and make sure the folders with the same name overlap.
I mean

- app folder from extension over app folder of your Magento instance
- design over design
- skin over skin
- ....